# Notice: Use of undefined constant - assumed ' '

Tags: constants

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am getting this error in my WordPress theme:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' in
>   .../themes/theme/homepage.php on line 10

Here is the contents of file it mentions:

```
<?php
    //Template Name: Home
    get_header();
?>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1><?php echo get_option('tiny_head_title'); ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo get_option('tiny_head_description'); ?></p>
    </header>
    <?php
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
        $home = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged' => $paged
        ));
        if ($home->have_posts()):
    ?>
    <div class="posts">
        <?php
            while ($home->have_posts()): $home->the_post();
            if (is_sticky()):
        ?>
            <article id='<?php the_ID();?>' <?php post_class('sticky');?>>
            <?php else: ?>
            <article  id='<?php the_ID(); ?>' <?php post_class();?>>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
            global $home;
            $total = $home->max_num_pages;
            if ($total > 1) {
            if (!$current_page = get_query_var('page'))
                $current_page = 1;
                $format = get_option('permalink_structure') ? 'page/%#%/' : '&page=%#%';
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format' => $format,
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total,
                'mid_size' => 4,
                'type' => 'plain'
            ));}
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: a copy and paste of your code does not produce an error

Comment: @Milo, I take it that means that it is a conflict with something else in my site?  My security plugin perhaps... it changes my /wp-content directory to "/new-name"

Comment: Can you run your code through a formatter and run it again with the new line number? Format it so that the <?php ?> tag spam is removed and your arrays and code are indented? I suspect the issue is inside the array passed into your `WP_Query` object, but it's not possible to tell when you have so much code on a single line

Comment: @TomJNowell, is there a formatter online that you recommend?  I've never done that before.  However, I have added blank lines before and after the line in question to ensure that it is the line causing the error.

Comment: [Here's the WP_Query formatted nicer](https://gist.github.com/Tarendai/5d88bd557f0db1a324db), If you're using Sublime Text there's a package for that, if you're using PHPStorm, there's a reformat code option

Comment: @TomJNowell, sorry, I don't understand what you mean by SublimeText or PHPStorm, so chances are I use neither.

Comment: [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a popular editor, [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is a powerful IDE

Comment: @TomJNowell alright, let me get the code cleaned up and I'll post it.

Comment: @TomJNowell, hope that helps.  Installing packages with that SublimeText thing was annoying.  I did the cleaning manually.

Comment: That's a vast improvement =) With that code, does it still show up on line 10?

Comment: @TomJNowell No Sir!  Error is gone! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @TomJNowell Please answer the question so I can vote it. :)

Comment: I would but I don't know what happened! Formatting should make debugging easier, but it doesn't normally fix the issue!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to @TomJNowell for suggesting running the snippet through a code cleaner, which fixed this issue!